# Is there any evidence for PIE *deikW- ‘feast’ to Greek deîp-?

Tags: historical-linguistics, greek

The interpretation of Linear B de-qo-no as ‘main dinner’ and po-ro-de-qo-no as ‘pre-dinner’ would only work if PIE *deikW- ‘feast’ > deîpnon.  However, it is cognate with words with -p-:

*deip- > OE tíber / tífer ‘sacrificial animal’
*dapno- > ON tafn ‘sacrifice / sacrificial animal’, L. daps ‘(sacrificial) feast’, damnum ‘expense/loss/harm’, G. dapánē ‘expense’

Is there any evidence for PIE *deikW- elsewhere?  If not, I would have to think LB de-qo-no was from some other root, with a different meaning.  If q also could represent some other sound, both KW and x < k / kh, then dékhomai could provide the root, also with oddities.  In dékomai ‘accept / receive/hold’ but Att. dékhomai there is no known reason for direct k > kh.  PIE *k > kh in Greek also in the endings -ikos \ -akos & -ikhos \ -akhos vs. Armenian -ik / -ak / -uk, also without explanation.  Since Arm. and G. are close relatives, and show odd -ikhos and -ik, an optional change of K is needed even if LB is not used as evidence for q as kh / x.

It’s possible de-qo-no is for *dexnos or *dexon(-os).  The range of meanings for dékhomai and its derivatives make an exact interpretation hard, but if this was indeed a record of what needed to be there for a feast, maybe a *dexnos or *pro-dexnos was a host or a group ‘welcome’ there, but a religious functionary is also possible.  If some k > x, even deikn- ‘show’, with pro- ‘act out (a religious play?)’ or ‘pantomime’ is also possible.  These might simply mean *dexnom or *dexonom < *dekh(o)no- ‘receptacle’ or ‘storage / reserve’ (to store excess food or provisions for later in the day(s)?), but finding out the exact meaning is not possible unless it is recognized that no IE cognates show *deikW- here, and LB q as both KW and x < k / kh is accepted.  More here, if needed:  [Are the q-series in Linear B also for kh and k before s?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/46167/are-the-q-series-in-linear-b-also-for-kh-and-k-before-s)

Comment: It’s far from certain that _δεῖπνον_ is cognate with those _*-p-_ words. It’s been suggested, certainly, but it’s not a suggestion without its formal issues. The _*-p-_ words are generally taken back to a root _*deh₂p-_, and getting _δεῖπνον_ from that root is less than straightforward. A root like _*dei̯kʷ-_ would be much more straightforward, but I don’t think it’s a generally reconstructed root. At least I’ve never seen it before, and it’s not in LIV² either.